# VS code interprets wrong comma from my keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, ascii

When I type a comma in VS code I get

```
，
```

but what I really want is

```
,
```

I'm not sure why there's two types of commas, but the first one is giving me run time errrors in python

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm not sure why there's two types of commas"

Well ... it is because Unicode defines them<sup>1</sup>. The first one is `U+FF0C : FULLWIDTH COMMA`. The second one is `U+002C : COMMA`

The latter is the one that *should* be bound to the "comma" key on your keyboard, but it is possible that something has changed your VSCode key bindings.  [This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) describes how to examine your VSCode key bindings.

But I think the more likely explanation is that you have copy-pasted some source code from (for example) a PDF file that is using `U+FF0C` instead of `U+002C` for cosmetic reasons ... or something.  It ia also possible that they were placed there by the author of the original document, or by their word-processing software.

You could try using the [Gremlins extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) to highlight any potentially troublesome characters in your source code.

---

<sup>1 - According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)), the purpose is *"so that older encodings containing both halfwidth and fullwidth characters can have lossless translation to/from Unicode."*.</sup>